# How to make a change event only run one time the event is called for a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm designing a multi dynamic select menus, i.e., I have a menu for brands, after the user select the brand, using JavaScript and AJAX, I will search for the models available from that brand and add them to the second select menu. This process repeats again but this time showing the features of the model selected.

To do this, and because I have many different areas that need the same system, I use a class with the same name in every brand select menu and another one to every model select menu.

```
  <div class='brand_select' id='14'>
    <%= f.collection_select :brand, Product.find_all_by_area(14, :group => 'brand'), :brand, :brand, :prompt => 'Choose brand' %>
  </div>
  <div class='model_select'>
     <%= f.collection_select :model, Product.find_all_by_area(14), :model, :model, :prompt => 'Choose model' %> 
  </div>

  <div class='brand_select' id='15'>
    <%= f.collection_select :brand, Product.find_all_by_area(15, :group => 'brand'), :brand, :brand, :prompt => 'Choose brand' %>
  </div>
  <div class='model_select'>
     <%= f.collection_select :model, Product.find_all_by_area(15), :model, :model, :prompt => 'Choose model' %> 
  </div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('.brand_select').change(function(event) {
    // option selected
    var brand=$(event.target).find('option:selected').val();

    // if none is selected
    if (brand == ''){
            $(event.target).parent().parent().find('.modelo_select').hide();
            $(event.target).parent().parent().find('.caracteristica').hide();
        }
    else {
        $(event.target).parent().parent().find('.modelo_select').show();
        // find id to search on the database
        var id=$(event.target).parent().attr('id');
        // find the target (id of the object)
        var target=$(event.target).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://"+location.host+"/model/"+brand+"/"+id+"/"+target,
            brand: brand,
            id: id,
            target: target
        });
    }  
});

$('.model_select').change(function(event) {
        // find model selected to search on the database
        var model=$(event.target).find('option:selected').val();
        // find brand selected to search on the database
        var brand=$(event.target).parent().parent().find('.marca_select').find('option:selected').val();
        // find id to search on the database
        var id=$(event.target).parent().parent().find('.marca_select').attr('id');
        // find the target (id of the object)
        var target=$(event.target).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://"+location.host+"/feature/"+brand+"/"+model+"/"+id+"/"+target,
            brand: brand,
            model: model,
            id: id,
            target: target
        });
});
```

This code works but it repeats the event change the same number of times as the classes with that name.

What I want to do is for the function to run only one time every time a change event is called for the class.

I don't know if this is possible with class structure that I have or if I have to associate an id or a class with different names for each area to the function.

Comment: Do you have only two levels ?

Comment: With all the code and the rather complicated explanation, I'm not sure I get it, but are you sure you're not just looking for [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ?

Comment: @Sandcar I only use two levels, the problem is because I use the class with the same name for each area, when one of the select inside one of the areas is selected the function is run x times the number of areas.

Comment: @adeneo the one() doesn't work, because I want the user to be able to change the selected option and the one would deactivated it after the first select.

When the user selects something on the select for brand id 14, it runs the function inside $('.brand_select').change() the number of times that I have the class '.brand_select', in this case 2 times, what I'm looking for is a solution for it to only run one time every time $('.brand_select').change() is called.

Comment: As a sidenote, a div element has no change event, and there is such a thing as closest() in jQuery, you don't have to use parent.parent.parent all the time, and by using the current scope (i.e. `this`) you can target the current menu only, not all of them.

Comment: can replace `var brand=$(event.target).find('option:selected').val();` with either `this.value` or `$(this).val()`. A `<select>` has same value as it's selected options

Comment: problem likely from using too many `.parent().parent()`  provide a demo in jsfiddle.net  , likely can simplify and better isolate traverses

Comment: @adeneo the rails helper he's using generates a select/option structure which triggers the change event and that always bubbles up, even if whatever's above it doesn't have change events by itself.

Comment: @trodrigues - I know, but asking a javascript question and giving us the serverside code isn't really a good idea, how are we supposed to know what the serverside code ends up looking like !

Comment: @charlietfl the .val() directly doesn't return a value, I have to put .find('option:selected').val() in order to get the value selected.

Comment: @charlietfl I did a demo on jsfiddle.net and there it only runs the event one time :/ 

I don't know where the problem should be, because the problem happens in all browsers, ie, if I put a alert, it will show always 2 times.

Comment: code duplicated somewhere maybe? Over simpified the html in demo perhaps? Hard for anyone to help if can't replicate

Comment: The code http://jsfiddle.net/LrNcN/4/ it works only one time, like it should, so I'm starting to think that the problem may be on the RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That for your help, I found out that the problem has nothing to do with Javascript but is instead on the Ruby on Rails.

I was adding on `application.html.erb` other js files and if you have the `//= require_tree` on the `application.js` it adds every js file in the tree, so adding js files on `application.html.erb` will make them repeat and cause strange behaviors like this one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why the event should fire twice because all you're doing with $(selector).change is saying that every time a change event fires on something with that selector you want to handle it. I even ran a quick test to be sure and it doesn't fire more than once.

Can you explain a bit better what the symptom actually is? As in, what actually happens twice? Does everything in your event handler happens twice?

I was thinking that your selectors for the actions you perform on the parents might be a bit too lax ($(event.target).parent().parent()) so if you only want to do something on the container where your event was fired that wouldn't be the best way (but then again I don't know what your end purpose is here).

Comment: Every time I select something, on the select under '.brand_select' it runs the the whole function of the event handler two times.


The parent() it's a bad execution, but I need to get out of the container to "grab" the information that I need to do a new query to the database, this way the code will gather the information from the surroundings and I don't have to repeat code.

Comment: I just tested everything and the problem as nothing to do with the javascript, because I erased the javascript from the file, run the application and pasted the javascript code on the console of the browser and it only runs the event one time per selection, as it should, so the problem is somewhere in the Ruby on Rails.

Thanks for the help.